# How do I get the rest path in a HandlerInterceptorAdapter without resolved path variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have a problem with my RestController interceptor.
My goal is to get the RestController path in a HandlerInterceptorAdapter and then use it to create metrics.
Via the interface HttpServletRequest I have access to the path, but it is resolved there.

Example of what I would like to get in my interceptor:

GET: object/123 // wrong

GET object/{id} // right

Is there any way to get the path without resolved variables?

Here is my implementation:

RestController:

```
@RestController
public class ObjectController
{
    @GetMapping("object/{id}")
    public String getObjectById(@PathVariable String id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
{
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            @Nullable ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            @Nullable Exception ex) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that Spring and Spring Boot both are already exposing metrics when you add `spring-boot-starter-actuator`? You are probably better of using what is supported and provided out-of-the-box then trying to reimplement your own. The Spring provided solution uses the defacto standard of Micrometer, which generates traces and metrics for calls. You can expose them to different backends (the simplest being logging but also things like prometheus).

Comment: Hi, yes I know that and I use those metrics already. But now I want to add some logic that the metrics should only be created if the request does not contain an Authorization header. Therefore I would like to have the path without resolved variables in the interceptor.

Comment: That shouldn't be done in an interceptor but you should integrate with the existing metrics instead.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. Maybe I can get this solved with the existing metrics.